# Getting basic information of devices that is connected to network

Tags: javascript, php, html, vb.net, networking

Base of my question: I am trying to create a simple code that can list basic information of a device that is connected to a network. For example, I have a wireless router, and there is a device(Mobile Phone) connected via wireless connection, and a device(Laptop/Desktop) that is connected via LAN. Now I want to find out what kind of device it is, also: the IP address, MAC address, processor, RAM, HDD/Internal Storage, Flash Drive(if connected) and let's say hardware manufacturer (If possible) etc..

Now I already have searched for these, and I found that this can be done by .NET, but I am thinking that this would be better if I can access this via web so even I'm at the office/work I can check the devices that are connected to our network. So I decided to do this using PHP, but don't know how to begin because I only have little knowledge of PHP, anyone can give me a sample of what I am tryng to achieve? Or any better reference on getting information of connected device on network via PHP?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to find all that information without having some extra tool installed on the devices. For example I think processor, RAM, HDD an flash drive information will probably be impossible, because of security reasons on the devices. On the other hand IP, MAC, and manufacturer you can probably retrieve somehow.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language. 
It will not allow you to enumerate connected devices due to security reasons.

Comment: In short i can never do this by using PHP?  it is ok to use VB.NET but my problem is i will need to install or even it is portable i will need a laptop or desktop everytime i wan to check my network. How about Javascript? do you think it can be? Thank you for answer!!

Comment: Directly using PHP, no. But what you can do is have VB.NET application  generate the HTML page containing the list of devices connected to your home network, and write the file to your web server directory running on a PC connected to the network. You can then access the you web server from anywhere to see the list. And of course, have VB.NET refresh the after a certain amount of time to always have an updated list.

Comment: looks like complicated for me. anyway, thank you so much! i will try to search for more information about what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP with NMAP:

https://nmap.org/

Some examples to look at:

[How to use Nmap in PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429527/how-to-use-nmap-in-php-exec)

[PHP trim nmap MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020558/php-trim-nmap-mac-address)